# Delay switching view changes

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to make some sort of delay in the view controllers changing. I need to be able to hit a button for the next page but also not have it change instantly. that is, somehow give it a timer or delay. Could someone point me in the right direction or give me a little help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(selector) withObject:self afterDelay:delay];
```

can be used to delay the execution of a method.  I've heard the sleep() function tossed around too, but it locks up the thread you're on.

NSTimer also has a helpful convenience method:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(selector)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
```

In particular, this timer will call the method named "selector" after 2 seconds, and not repeat itself.

EDIT: in your case, you probably want to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` like so:

```
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then within myMethod, perform your delay, which looks like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myTransition) withObject:self afterDelay:4.00];
```

Comment: really new to this but I dont see a time on the first code so how do i set that and on the NSTimer code here is that 4.00 the timer, where would that go in with the button im trying to delay?